# VAR() or dynlm() or lm()

Tags: r, time-series, least-squares, econometrics, vector-autoregression

Can anybody tell me something about the difference between the functions `VAR()` and `dynlm()`? I thought I could do my VAR with OLS also with the `lm()` function, but found out that I can not include lags. This problem is solved by using `dynlm()`. I tried `VAR()` and `dynlm()` with the same data and also changed the type of the VAR function ("const" / "trend" /"none" / "both"), but in none of the cases the results were the same. Does anybody know the difference?

```
Data Example (only 100 rows of my time series with over 1000 rows):

      Price Open_Interest_All
1992-10-06 -0.781222672        1.63119379
1992-10-13 -0.226928010        4.05849973
1992-10-20 -0.314059754        0.74296670
1992-10-27  0.427535236        4.69469707
1992-11-03 -0.066975848       -8.97727509
1992-11-10 -1.105733849       13.60848986
1992-11-17 -0.033504156       -0.86606938
1992-11-24  0.132090521        3.09942608
1992-12-01  0.451677760       -6.96875467
1992-12-08  0.059010297        1.45547915
1992-12-15  0.018143072        2.47922886
1992-12-22  0.415489498        0.11104701
1992-12-29  0.281748150       -0.01741099
1993-01-05  1.264093684        0.75242942
1993-01-12 -1.765301997       -0.16864140
1993-01-19  0.352909608        1.23869888
1993-01-26  0.152561942        5.16469475
1993-02-02 -0.306023610       -1.88288581
1993-02-09  0.371154802       -0.22569400
1993-02-16 -0.096699431        0.72290467
1993-02-23 -0.216939288       -1.03640733
1993-03-02 -0.692525272        7.32922042
1993-03-09  0.148512407       -0.83248916
1993-03-16  0.053258877       -9.34412387
1993-03-23  0.282899028       -2.27865356
1993-03-30 -0.348375291       -0.68304626
1993-04-06 -0.701583175        5.13726283
1993-04-13 -0.643717452        7.49539668
1993-04-20 -2.315215806        6.78579388
1993-04-27  0.728123084       -7.89513692
1993-05-04 -0.401917826        1.93334817
1993-05-11 -0.820260275       -0.41889123
1993-05-18 -0.136744342        0.17780875
1993-05-25  0.851391229        5.73901054
1993-06-01 -1.030441814        2.02329734
1993-06-08  0.622336509       -0.47102737
1993-06-15  0.188830476        1.12995553
1993-06-22  0.425932387        3.25510238
1993-06-29  0.094860323       -1.15090784
1993-07-06  0.690949433       -3.84819577
1993-07-13 -0.555562379       -0.79792963
1993-07-20 -0.003165141        0.26002615
1993-07-27  0.303670755       -2.04747741
1993-08-03  0.173833160        0.14447390
1993-08-10 -0.361775029        4.78484100
1993-08-17  0.384427420       -3.66029272
1993-08-24  0.427606006        0.68034298
1993-08-31 -0.138889246       -7.61964095
1993-09-07  0.336480002       -2.54707323
1993-09-14 -1.121502023        5.46051062
1993-09-21 -1.763129531       13.11181789
1993-09-28  0.039080472        0.86031698
1993-10-05 -0.966905912       -4.20461016
1993-10-12  0.218149112       -2.12196119
1993-10-19 -0.817582360       -1.80785218
1993-10-26 -0.077143308        4.02653854
1993-11-02  0.079626855        0.64359810
1993-11-09  0.451802406        6.08728086
1993-11-16 -0.305816356        4.74542449
1993-11-23  0.217000320        4.48037134
1993-11-30 -0.188669087       -1.17994159
1993-12-07  0.747784520        5.22816662
1993-12-14  0.636011468       -2.22521990
1993-12-21  0.373247064       -0.52307968
1993-12-28  0.046941753       -0.95758768
1994-01-04 -0.810928287       -1.05574558
1994-01-11  0.490505014       -2.23947004
1994-01-18  0.699126287        1.47016108
1994-01-25  0.420702924       -5.33040334
1994-02-01 -0.034364270        1.03293264
1994-02-08  0.178692037        7.82838866
1994-02-15 -0.763248370       -4.77697912
1994-02-22  0.834492829       -4.39362728
1994-03-01 -0.319921226       -5.77740405
1994-03-08  0.428953703        6.08511360
1994-03-15  0.293429418        3.33746465
1994-03-22  0.212134960        8.28017661
1994-03-29  0.015434084       -3.84063215
1994-04-05 -0.819101724      -12.37463070
1994-04-12 -0.241797314       -6.35085378
1994-04-19 -0.110199011       -0.52875672
1994-04-26  0.292877781        8.25096506
1994-05-03  0.769091229        8.93992009
1994-05-10  1.335381796       -3.14410505
1994-05-17  1.218414811       -6.21162283
1994-05-24  0.915342249       -1.06778949
1994-05-31 -0.899495962        3.65817336
1994-06-07 -0.033983195       -4.82433827
1994-06-14  1.561915814        4.23026763
1994-06-21 -0.066335053       -1.33347133
1994-06-28 -0.385756193       -5.93684313
1994-07-05  0.991119380       -5.67886504
1994-07-12 -0.398792460       -8.50476149
1994-07-19  0.232917128        6.45658144
1994-07-26  0.382266943       -9.35866297
1994-08-02 -1.190583357       -0.50190110
1994-08-09  0.364675303       -5.42680501
1994-08-16 -0.070737617        1.57683454
1994-08-23 -0.167435051       -3.93086516
1994-08-30  0.928324476        5.51263721

VARexample <- VAR(example, p=5, type="const")
lmexample <- lm(example$Price[6:100]~example$Price[5:99]+example$Price[4:98]+example$Price[3:97]+example$Price[2:96]+example$Price[1:95]+example$Open_Interest_All[5:99]+example$Open_Interest_All[4:98]+example$Open_Interest_All[3:97] + example$Open_Interest_All[2:96] + example$Open_Interest_All[1:95])
dynlmexample <- dynlm(example$Price~L(example$Price,1:5) + L(example$Open_Interest_All,1:5))

VARcoeffsexample <- as.data.frame(coef(VARexample)$Price[c(11,1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10),1])
lmcoeffsexample <- as.data.frame(coef(lmexample))
dynlmcoeffsexample <- as.data.frame(coef(dynlmexample))

compare <- data.frame(VARcoeffsexample[,1], lmcoeffsexample[,1], dynlmcoeffsexample[,1])
rownames(compare) <- rownames(VARcoeffsexample)



Output: 
> compare
                     VARcoeffsexample...1. lmcoeffsexample...1. dynlmcoeffsexample...1.
const                         0.0162815782         0.0162815782             0.016408246
Price.l1                     -0.0233716524        -0.0233716524            -0.062759716
Price.l2                      0.1262282115         0.1262282115             0.050038501
Price.l3                      0.1444267851         0.1444267851             0.103449318
Price.l4                     -0.0806846153        -0.0806846153             0.005414185
Price.l5                     -0.0197842734        -0.0197842734            -0.048802520
Open_Interest_All.l1         -0.0176241595        -0.0176241595            -0.022186654
Open_Interest_All.l2          0.0166671079         0.0166671079            -0.008759684
Open_Interest_All.l3          0.0205802095         0.0205802095            -0.007958906
Open_Interest_All.l4         -0.0384040280        -0.0384040280            -0.003796186
Open_Interest_All.l5          0.0006342804         0.0006342804            -0.029456337
```

So lm() and VAR() are the same coefficients, but dynlm() is different...

Comment: If you make lags manually (e.g. using the function `embed`), you can use them in `lm`. (This does not answer your question, so I am only posting this as a comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to spell out the difference in results. But it sure is possible to get the same results in either package, as - as you correctly point out - all three commands ultimately just run OLS regressions.

It is with different degrees of ease, though, reflecting the purpose of the packages. `lm` is, of course, for all sorts of regressions, while the other two explicitly have time series regressions in mind, and `vars` even multivariate ones.

Here is an example.

```
library(dynlm)
library(vars)

x <- ts(rnorm(100)) # ts is relevant for dynlm, see discussion in comments below!
y <- ts(rnorm(100))

# at a glance
all.equal(c(coef(dynlm(x ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3))), coef(dynlm(y ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3)))),
          c(coef(VAR(cbind(x,y), p = 3, type = "const"))$x[c(7,1,3,5,2,4,6),1], coef(VAR(cbind(x,y), p = 3, type = "const"))$y[c(7,1,3,5,2,4,6),1]),
          c(coef(lm(x[4:100]~x[3:99]+x[2:98]+x[1:97]+y[3:99]+y[2:98]+y[1:97])), coef(lm(y[4:100]~x[3:99]+x[2:98]+x[1:97]+y[3:99]+y[2:98]+y[1:97]))),
          check.attributes=F)

dynlm(x ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3))
dynlm(y ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3))

VAR(cbind(x,y), p = 3, type = "const")


lm(x[4:100]~x[3:99]+x[2:98]+x[1:97]+y[3:99]+y[2:98]+y[1:97])
lm(y[4:100]~x[3:99]+x[2:98]+x[1:97]+y[3:99]+y[2:98]+y[1:97])
```

Output:

```
> dynlm(x ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3))

Time series regression with "ts" data:
Start = 4, End = 100

Call:
dynlm(formula = x ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   L(x, 1:3)1   L(x, 1:3)2   L(x, 1:3)3   L(y, 1:3)1   L(y, 1:3)2   L(y, 1:3)3  
   -0.14797     -0.13608      0.04310     -0.14119      0.03736     -0.20556     -0.07980  


> dynlm(y ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3))

Time series regression with "ts" data:
Start = 4, End = 100

Call:
dynlm(formula = y ~ L(x, 1:3) + L(y, 1:3))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   L(x, 1:3)1   L(x, 1:3)2   L(x, 1:3)3   L(y, 1:3)1   L(y, 1:3)2   L(y, 1:3)3  
   0.001093     0.008268     0.101429    -0.122984     0.039118     0.060185    -0.194614  


> VAR(cbind(x,y), p = 3, type = "const")

VAR Estimation Results:
======================= 

Estimated coefficients for equation x: 
====================================== 
Call:
x = x.l1 + y.l1 + x.l2 + y.l2 + x.l3 + y.l3 + const 

       x.l1        y.l1        x.l2        y.l2        x.l3        y.l3       const 
-0.13608446  0.03735653  0.04310129 -0.20555950 -0.14119156 -0.07980048 -0.14797419 


Estimated coefficients for equation y: 
====================================== 
Call:
y = x.l1 + y.l1 + x.l2 + y.l2 + x.l3 + y.l3 + const 

        x.l1         y.l1         x.l2         y.l2         x.l3         y.l3        const 
 0.008267836  0.039117666  0.101428691  0.060184617 -0.122984226 -0.194613595  0.001093310 



> lm(x[4:100]~x[3:99]+x[2:98]+x[1:97]+y[3:99]+y[2:98]+y[1:97])

Call:
lm(formula = x[4:100] ~ x[3:99] + x[2:98] + x[1:97] + y[3:99] + 
    y[2:98] + y[1:97])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      x[3:99]      x[2:98]      x[1:97]      y[3:99]      y[2:98]      y[1:97]  
   -0.14797     -0.13608      0.04310     -0.14119      0.03736     -0.20556     -0.07980  


> lm(y[4:100]~x[3:99]+x[2:98]+x[1:97]+y[3:99]+y[2:98]+y[1:97])

Call:
lm(formula = y[4:100] ~ x[3:99] + x[2:98] + x[1:97] + y[3:99] + 
    y[2:98] + y[1:97])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      x[3:99]      x[2:98]      x[1:97]      y[3:99]      y[2:98]      y[1:97]  
   0.001093     0.008268     0.101429    -0.122984     0.039118     0.060185    -0.194614
```

Comment: I added the data. You helped me with the lm() function and I now get the same results for VAR() and lm(), but not for dynlm()...

Comment: It will be related to you not declaring the variables as `ts` objects. Something like this works for me: `library(vars)
library(dynlm)

my_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", header=F, dec=",")
example <- data.frame(my_data)
example$Price <- ts(example$V1)
example$Open_Interest_All <- ts(example$V2)
example$V1 <- NULL
example$V2 <- NULL

VARexample <- VAR(example, p=5, type="const")
dynlmexample <- dynlm(example$Price~L(example$Price,1:5) + L(example$Open_Interest_All,1:5))`

Comment: Needed to create two separate variables ('x <- xts_to_ts(example$Price)' & 'y <- xts_to_ts(example$Open_Interest_All)' ) and then it worked and all three functions created the same coefficients. Interesting, that the function lm() doesn't know we have a ts when str(example) is a xts object. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChristophHanck, this is off topic here, but I have been struggling with some time series questions that you might be able to answer. So if you find the time and interest, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512037) is the last one, and some other ones are linked in it. Thank you!